# How can I overwrite method “__(”?

Tags: laravel, laravel-localization

In laravel using location method `__(`, like :

```
$managerAccessText = __('common.As you have manager access');
```

I got text

```
common.As you have manager access
```

in case if this label was not found

How can I overwrite method `__(` if i want to remove file name like in case above?

```
"laravel/framework": "^9.19",
```

Comment: What stops you to add translation in this file?

Comment: Why do you want to remove a file name? I’m not getting your problem not the question .. maybe both ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You understand that this function is for the international translation of strings according to the current locale of the application.

Unless you provide specific translation then the string will be output exactly as provided.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/localization#retrieving-translation-strings

You can include placeholders in the string where values passed to the function will be inserted into the translated string.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/localization#replacing-parameters-in-translation-strings